# How to Prevent Submitting Data during Refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

as i am developing a web application in asp.net, There is 4 text boxes to provide user deatils and a button to save the information in DB. When User click the button to Insert the user deatil, it is saved in DB perfectly, but the problem is when the user  Refreshes the page, that data is again re inserted / resubmitted, i want to make sure that duplicate submission should be avoided .

Please any suggestion, code samples, to avoid this situation are welcome ( in c#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (also known as *Redirect after post*) pattern. It simply consists in redirecting after a successful post, so that the user refresh results in an idempotent GET to be done rather than a POST. It has the additional advantage that the browser "forgets" about the POST in its history, which means the back button won't submit either.

Comment: can u tell me how to implement PRG pattern in asp.net

Comment: still it is allowing to submit :( . how do i prevent it. i used Response.EnD(), and checked whether cliet is connected or not. still also same . can u provide some sample code . or other method

Comment: Ask another question, explaining that you tried to implement the pattern, and showing your code. You must have done something wrong. You must use Response.Redirect (and not Response.End) after the data is inserted in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Put a field in page call it status for example, after submitting first time it's populated with SUCCESS. If it is the do not save again.

Not the ultimate solution for sure.